# Tearing when watching Netflix on AMD, Firefox and Wayland

Tags: gnome, firefox, 17.10, amd-graphics, wayland

When watching Netflix in Ubuntu 17.10, Wayland, Firefox or Chrome and AMD Radeon R9 Nano, there is a lot of tearing. When using X.Org instead of Wayland everything works fine. I'm using graphics drivers from PPA `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`. Is there a way to get Wayland working without tearing?

Comment: Is hardware acceleration enabled in Chrome?

Comment: @dobey I have tested both enabled and disabled, no difference.

Comment: Sounds likely to be a bug in the Wayland stack then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem by forcing acceleration to true in `about:config`:

```
layers.acceleration.force-enabled
```